# How to run metabase on ec2 instance (without elastic beanstalk)

Tags: amazon-ec2, metabase

i am newbie in Metabase, also i don't have much knowledge about AWS. i have EC2 instance and i want to run Metabase on EC2 instance without elastic beanstalk. is this possible? if yes than how? and if no than why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of running metabase in a EC2 instance is following their own docs on how to run the application from the .jar file. Metabase has an awesome documentation so I recommend you take a look at it.

In simple steps you need to :

1. Install Java 7
2. Download Metabase .jar file
3. Run .jar file `java -jar metabase.jar`

The application will be running on port 3000 (http://:3000). Remember to open inbound rules on the EC2 security group. Important to say this setup is recommended only for testing. If you want to have an instance in production you should worry about other things such as pointing the application database to a more robust database like PostgreSQL or MySQL.

**Link to official docs:** http://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/operations-guide/running-the-metabase-jar-file.html

Comment: Correct, however it won't run as a service, so if you reboot the machine metabase won't be running.

Comment: You are right @facundo. It is just a quick way to start playing with Metabase. For production use it needs a more robust solution

Comment: What type of ec2 instance is recommended for metabase?

Comment: @Ayush It varies a lot and I will answer as someone that is not a specialist in infrastructure. It will depend on how many users you will have accessing the platform. My suggestion is to start small and monitor CPU and memory. On AWS, starting small would mean a t2.micro or a t2.small. It will be easy to scale up if needed.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but it might be useful in the future.
I wrote down a full tutorial on setting up Metabase on a standalone ec2 instance.
The article answers many common questions (e.g. setting it up as a service).
https://itisoktoask.me/metabase-on-ec2-amazon-linux/

Comment: providing a brief answer here itself, along with the link would help.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a few problems on the way. This is how I finally made it work:

- [Download Java 8 to your instance](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (Java 7 is not enough for the current version of Metabase).
  You can get the download link from the website, `SSH` to your EC2 instance and use `wget` to download Java 8 to your instance using the link: `wget DownloadLink`. Alternatively you can download it locally and transfer it to the EC2 instance using `SCP`.
- Install Java 8
- [Download metabse.jar](https://www.metabase.com/start/jar.html)
- Run Metabase: `java -jar metabase.jar`
- Access Metabase by browsing http://EC2IP:3000/ where EC2IP must be replaced with IP address of the EC2 instance.

If you could not connect try the following steps:

- make sure the port 3000 is not blocked by the firewall (this is usually the case if you are connecting from your company's network)
- Make sure port 3000 is allowed in inbound rules of the EC2 instance.
- Add the IP and host of your instance to /etc/hosts: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`. Add ip and host like  `10.10.10.10  ip-10-10-10-10` as a new line.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you add you public IP address to you hosts file at /etc/hosts. this fixed it for me